# How to strike out a table row which caries a particular php value?

Tags: php, html

I want to apply text-decoration:line-through to a table row which will be looped as per a mysql query. i want to strike out the row only if a variable's value is Not Interested

in the following loop there is a table row with id line. and there is a variable $status. I want the tabel row to get striked out if the value of $status comes "Not Interested" how can i do that?

```
    while ($prow=mysql_fetch_object($productname))
        {
        $pname.=$prow->name.'<br />';
        }


     $staffname=mysql_query("select name from staff where sid='$assignedto' or flag='$assignedto'");
        if(mysql_num_rows($staffname) > 1)
        {
        echo "<tr id='line'";
        if($count %2==0)
        echo "bgcolor='white' style='height:10px;'";
        echo ">";

        $count++;

        ?>

    <td>

    <span class="time"><a title="<?echo $added;?>" ></a></span>


        </td>
        <?
        echo "<td >".$name. "</td>";
        echo "<td>".$status."</td>";
        echo "<td >".$phone." "."|"." ".$mobile. "</td>";
        // echo "<td >".$email. "</td>";
        echo "<td >".$city. "</td>";


        echo "<td >".$pname. "</td>";
        echo "<td >".$sname. "</td>";
        echo "<td >".$lastactivity. "</td>";
    ?>

 </table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
if ($status == 'Not Interested') { $strike = 'text-decoration:line-through'; }
else { $strike = ''; }
```

And then

```
echo "<tr id='line'";
if($count %2==0)
echo "bgcolor='white' style='height:10px; $strike'";
echo ">";
```

If $status is not `'Not Interested'` it will simply add `''` instead of `text-decoration:line-through`

Answer (score 2):

Within the loop you can check the value of $status, and if it matches "Not Interested", you just add a specific CSS class(example: class="line-through") to that row, and you handle the rest in CSS like this:

```
tr.line-through td{
    text-decoration:line-through
}
```